# Some computers in my subnet do not recognize names of other pc's

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, subnet

I have two subnets:

1. 192.168.0.1-255
2. 192.168.50.1-255

Ewerything works via VPN (because physically computer from both subnets are in different locations). We also have active directory. Now, the first subnet has all the main servers etc. Computers that are located in this subnet work just fine (i.e. they see all the pc's in the both subnets).

The problem is with second subnet. Some of the pc's (as far we didn't recognize any pattern here) have problem with recognizing pc's from first subnet by name (recognizing by ip works fine). There is totally no pattern here - we saw examples of pc's, that do recognize everything just after simple relog, but then after another relog it didn't work again.

Is it a problem with our domain/active directory? Or our DNS server? What can cause problems here?

Comment: Are they having problems with NetBIOS names (no domain), e.g. \\FileServ5, or with DNS names, e.g. "\\fileserv5.contoso.com", or both? (I would expect NetBIOS names to fail as they rely on broadcasts which should not be going between the subnets.)

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker: Yes, it's all about NetBIOS names.

Comment: @user218133 Yeah, don't use NETBIOS where you can possibly avoid it... and since you've gotten an answer below that enables you to avoid it, you should do so. :)

Answer (score 3):

Configure the DNS suffix correctly on all clients and servers.

The easy way of doing this is through Group Policy
[image]

You should also configure it on your DHCP server(s) if you use DHCP, as not all clients are domain-joined in all environments. You do this by configuring DHCP option 015 and 119.

For statically adressed clients/servers (not served by DHCP) you can set this manually in the advanced TCP/IP settings on each connection

[image]

Comment: This is completely unnecessary for domain joined computers.